# Open Contrail API, post request on project resource

Tags: api, rest, post, cloud

I'm working on a cloud project and I have to use [Contrail](https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-web-core) it provides a RESTful API to use, but it is [documentation](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/contrail/information-products/pathway-pages/api-server/tutorial_with_rest.html) is too small. I would like to know how to perform rest requests, especially post requests on "project" resource.

Answer (score 2):

Each Contrail config node provides supported API details(searchable) at http://:8082/documentation/index.html

You could also check [here](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/contrail/information-products/pathway-pages/api-server/rest_reference.html) which is a bit old but should serve your project API needs.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a documentation about Contrail api, For each resource I mention the allowed methods and which parameters to integrate on the request body and I test it until I get it to work finally I put an example. I haven't finished the documentation, I stopped working on Open Contrail. The documentation is my personal try maybe it would be useful and maybe it contains some mistakes, Thus, I would like to share it. You can find it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tucuaa673j6d4ay/contrail_api.pdf?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is old, but as there are no other answers I thought I would contribute one. Were you interested in an answer or just wanted to share the documentation you'd written? I agree with you that Contrail documentation is very scarce, and every attempt to contribute to it should be appreciated. I had to integrate with Contrail API a while ago, and found out that in some cases I had to call OpenStack APIs to get the job done (Contrail is built on top of OpenStack). Project and user management were some of them.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, I'm really happy to see a "bro" that worked on Open Contrail ! Yes I was interested in an answer, but no one could help, so after 10 days, I and my colleague decided to stop working on it, then I decided to share my small documentation whit people who shared the pain of Contrail with me. Yes I know, me too, I took a look into OpenStack when I was working on Contrail. Any way, thank you for your response !